# Domain renewal/transfer gandi.net

Tags: domains

I'm in kind of a difficult situation here: I have a domain (a .at domain) and transfered it to gandi.net a couple of months ago. Now it's time to renew my domain but when I tried to do the renewal it just said the renewal could not be done online. After that I got an invoice from the nic.at (registry for .at domains) which stated that gandi wouldnt pay any more invoices for my domain. I can't access the domain over the gandi.net website so I cant change any dns/whois information. I can't transfer my domain back to gandi since the mail address in the whois was an @contact.gandi.net which doesnt exist anymore since the domain isn't listed anymore in my gandi account.

I contacted the support of gandi and got no answer what so ever(for over 1 week now). The domain is about to run out + I have to pay the invoice from nic.at if I don't have it transfered within the next couple of weeks.

Now my question is: What do you suggest my next step is towards regaining control over my domain? Did anyone experience simular issues with gandi.net?

Thanks for the help guys, I'm desperate for ideas/suggestions

Comment: You should try to re-contact them in any way. Did you try [their forum](http://groups.gandi.net/en) ?

Comment: I tried their forums, and I've written in total 5 support tickets.
I've gotten an answer to one of them which didnt help me at all and just said that "all this is highly unusual"

Comment: It reinforce my idea regarding Gandi, I don't like them...

Comment: Gandi always respond to my e-mails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you are going to resolve this issue is with Gandi's support. I would contact them again. If no answer from them within a responsible amount of time you might be able to contact nic.at and request the admin/tech email is changed to yours so you can move it away. When is this domain due to expire? According to the nic.at website domains drop 28 days after expiry if you do not renew. So a domain back ordering service maybe quicker then opening a dispute with nic.at but carry a risk.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the domain owner (check the domain WHOIS entries), you can directly contact nic.at by sending them a fax. Also, have you registered (pending transfer) your domain with another hosting provider?

There are some cases, an old hoster isn't responding anymore, for these cases there are rules, even if your email adress in the WHOIS isn't valid anymore, important is only that your name (and perhaps your adress) is still the same like it is in the WHOIS of your domain, then you can use a signed FAX or letter to nic.at or to your new domain registrar.

And you better hurry up, I know cases a domain was lost because of this. If it's urgently, I can provide you my email adress to support you more detailed (if you don't see it in my profile here), also support in German language.